# How to decode objects sent from netty server and encode objects to netty server in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter, netty

I have made a [question to send/receive from netty server to flutter client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664831/how-to-send-to-netty-server-through-flutter-client) already, but I have succeeded in creating the connection. However, my new problem is that the data sent from the netty server is a byte array (I believe anyways) and I can't seem to figure out how to decode the byte array to object. I still would like to have my original question answered since an answer could be a better method than what I am doing at the moment. How would I go from decrypting a byte array sent from a netty server ([code here](https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat/blob/master/java/server/src/main/java/com/github/fernthedev/server/Server.java#L275)) and encoding a byte array? (I am using a ObjectEncoder and ObjectDecoder for netty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netty has different codecs for serializing data. The default `ObjectEncoder` appears to serialize a header including the java class uid and then appends a normal java object serialization. It's unlikely that you will want to implement a counterpart to that in Dart.

You need to find a data representation that you can generate/parse in netty and Dart. At one extreme you could use netty `ByteBuf`. It'll be fairly clear how netty is serializing into `ByteBuf` and you can mimic that at the Dart end using `ByteData`. At the other extreme, you might barely use netty's serialization. You could encode your Java object into a utf8 JSON string, send that, and at the dart end simply decode the utf8 and the json. Of course, that doesn't give you a compact wire representation. If you want a compact representation that's available in Java and Dart, consider protobuf.

If you are getting two systems in two different languages to interoperate, *you* need to be in charge of how they are both doing the serialization/deserialization. Using netty's `ObjectEncoder` seems like a bad idea as it relies too heavily on Java's internal object serialization, which has no counterpart at the Dart end.

Comment: Agree with protobuf. Seems like the right solution for this scenar

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. I will attempt to follow this concept, if I need additional help I can always ask again :)